# Unable to create azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container with indexing_policy block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

According to the [documentation on Terraform.io](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/cosmosdb_sql_container.html#indexing_policy) for azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container, it says I can include an indexing_policy block. However, when I run `terraform plan` I get errors:

> Error: Unsupported block type
>
> on main.tf line 912, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container"
> "AccountActivity":  912:   indexing_policy {
>
> Blocks of type "indexing_policy" are not expected here.

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "AccountActivity" {
  name                = "AccountActivity"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.backendResourceGroup.name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.AzureCosmosAccount.name
  database_name       = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.AzureCosmosDbCache.name
  default_ttl         = 2592000
  throughput          = 2500
  
  indexing_policy {
    indexing_mode = "Consistent"

    included_path {
      path = "/*"
    }

    excluded_path {
      path = "/\"_etag\"/?"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `terraform version` output:

```
terraform version
Terraform v0.13.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm v2.30.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.20.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v2.3.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching GitHub, I finally found that support for the indexing_policy block was added [in this commit 26 days ago](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/commit/a7213a96b1e4dbfa1d7308835e63b3f5f56b8e75). The documentation doesn't mention this, nor does the [release notes for azurerm v2.31.1](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases). After updating my main.tf file with the latest version for azurerm and running `terraform init` the `terraform plan` command worked without issue.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version         = "~>2.31.1"
  features {}
}
```